# Verify part of endpoint with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Is there a way to verify a part of the endpoint with Selenium?

For example, I have a link:
**https://somesite.com/verify_text/123**

I want to verify that the endpoint contains **/verify_text/**

Thank you!

Comment: Is  ```/verify_text/``` always followed by a number?

Comment: Yes. there is always a number

Comment: Okay...Check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
url = "https://somesite.com/verify_text/123"

url_lst = url.split('/')

while("" in url_lst) :
    url_lst.remove("")

if url_lst[-2] == "verify_text":
    print("Contains verify_text")
```

Output:

```
Contains verify_text
```

Comment: Thank you! With small corrections, I can make it work.

Comment: To get the URL with Selenium I will use driver.current_url function

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution using selenium.

```
driver.get("https://somesite.com/verify_text/123")
current_url = driver.current_url
assert "/verify_text/" in current_url
```

I hope it will help somebody.